# Allow additional attributes, like placeholder text or icon, on model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-bootstrap4

I use modelforms in several places in my app, and have written custom bootstrap form rendering. It's working well, but I'd like to be able to add `addon_before` to some of my fields (example, for `twitter_username` i'd set `addon_before='https://twitter.com/`. I'd also like to specify icon classes and placeholder text for some fields.

I know I can do this in the form rendering, but I render the same fields in several different forms, and I dont want to repeat the form settings. using the `twitter_username` example, is there a way to globally set wherever that field is used in a modelform, to include a set of attributes and values

`{'addon_before': 'https://twitter.com/', 'placeholder': '@username', 'icon': 'fa-twitter'}`

Would love any suggestions!

Comment: Did you manage to fix this in the end @Brenden?

Comment: No, never figured it out 

Comment: Too bad - thanks for the reply